# Why is $3$ divided by $X^{1/2}$ equal to $3X^{-1/2}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have the equation "$Y = (X + 3) / \sqrt{X}$ "

The solutions say that this can be simplified to $X^{1/2} + 3X^{-1/2}$.

I understand that  $\sqrt{X}$ is equal to $X^{1/2}$. So $X$ divided by $X^{1/2}$ is $X^{1/2}$.

However, how does $3$ divided by $X^{1/2}$ give $3X^{-1/2}$? Should it not be $3X^{1/2}$ ?

Comment: Laws of indices $1/x^a = x^{-a} \, \forall \, a$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have
$$
\frac{x + 3}{\sqrt{x}} = \frac{x}{\sqrt{x}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}
$$
and you've successfully simplified the first bit. The rule you need for simplifying the second is this:
$$
\frac{1}{x^k} = x^{-k}.
$$

If you multiply through by the denominator, you see that this is the same as
$$
1 = x^k \cdot x^{-k}
$$, 
which is why $x^{-k}$ is *defined* to be $\frac{1}{x^k}$.

In your case, $k = \frac{1}{2}$, and
$$
\frac{1}{x^{\frac{1}{2}}} = x ^ {-\frac{1}{2}}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

There is a convention that multiplying by a value raised to a negative power is the same as dividing by that value raised to the corresponding positive power.  That is why it is $3X^{-\frac{1}{2}}$, which is equivalent to $3(x^{\frac{1}{2}})^{-1}$.